# Jquery id selector in html object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've recently started building an app for a forum that's just horrendous on a mobile view. To do this, I'm using simple_html_dom_parser to read out the parts of the forum/website that I'm interested in (for this issue, I only want posts, poster and date posted, + the pages). I have all the information I have on my php page, but for the life of me I can't get the data out using jquery.

```
$.get("data.php", {thread: <? echo $_GET['thread']; ?>})
    .done(function(data) {
            var datahtml = $(data).html();
            var stuff = [];
            var i = 0;
            var pages = $(datahtml).find("div#pages"); // This is causing my issues
            console.log(pages);
            $(datahtml+" .threadpost").each(function(k,v) { // building a json object with the information from data here, not relevant
```

As you can see, I made a variable (datahtml) to hold the html from the returned var "data" so I can traverse this data. I then use .each successfully to read and get the information I want. However, I can't find the contents of the div#pages.

Here's the funny bit from chrome console:

```
[prevObject: n.fn.init[91], context: undefined, selector: "div#pages", jquery: "2.1.4", constructor: function…]
```

Expanding that object returns, at the very bottom:

```
90: div#pages
```

Now, I'm absolutely certain that I'm doing something silly here, but I've tried doing the selection in so many ways now, I'm starting to get annoyed, which really isnt helping my productivity.

Comment: Some sample HTML might help improve your odds of getting an answer on this.  It'd be useful to see _what's_ being parsed as well as how you're attempting to do it.

Comment: Try `var pages = datahtml.find("div#pages");`.

Comment: html pasted @ http://pastebin.com/Ky87kWbk
@kel: Uncaught TypeError: datahtml.find is not a function

Comment: @rlweb -- My bad, I just tested this out. It should be `var pages = $(data).find("div#pages");`

Comment: There we go, perfect - any idea why it works to search in data, but not datahtml?

Comment: Because the `datahtml` is a string and not a jQuery object. It would again work with `$(datahtml)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the data var and dump the datahtml stuff. The jQuery html function is grabbing the html that matches, you want to use an element, so it wasn't returning the correct html.

```
$.get("data.php", {thread: <? echo $_GET['thread']; ?>})
    .done(function(data) {
            var stuff = [];
            var i = 0;
            var pages = $(data).find("div#pages"); // This is causing my issues
            console.log(pages);
            $(datahtml+" .threadpost").each(function(k,v) { // building a json object with the information from data here, not relevant
```